# Scan from Hbase for a date and inserting into Hive partition (dt)

Tags: hive, hbase

I have a hbase table.
I want to scan one day's data from Hbase and insert into Hive table partition ( same date) .
Can you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create an external table over Hbase in Hive? Use date as a partition key? Not sure but i think even dynamic partition should also work!

-Vivek

Comment: you mean to say the partition will automatically pick up from date column ??